# Reverse order count sort vector deallocation

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, memory, vector

I'm learning how sorting algorithms work. I've implemented the counting sort in C++:

```cpp
vector<int> counting_sort_dec(vector<int> &A, int k) {
    vector<int> B(A.size());
    vector<int> C(k + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        C[A[i]]++;

    for (int i = C.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        C[i - 1] += C[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        C[A[i]]--;
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
    }
    return B;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> A = {2, 5, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3};

    cout << "Counting sort" << endl;
    for (auto e : A)
        cout << e << " ";
    cout << endl;

    vector<int> A_sorted = counting_sort_dec(A, 5);
    for (auto e : A_sorted)
        cout << e << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I stop the debugger at `return B;`, I see a correctly sorted array, `[5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0]`; however, after that, the program crashes with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT). It seems that vector B deallocates before it is returned. How can I convince it to not do it? The weirdest thing is that I wrote a function that sorts in ascending order and it works with no issues:

```cpp
vector<int> counting_sort(vector<int> &A, int k) {
    vector<int> B(A.size());
    vector<int> C(k + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        C[A[i]]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < C.size(); i++)
        C[i] += C[i - 1];

    for (int i = A.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        C[A[i]]--;
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
    }
    return B;
}
```

What is the issue with the descending order?

Comment: 1.) `B` might be deleted after a copy of it is stored as return value or it might be returned directly if NRVO is applied. 2.) I would focus on `for (int i = C.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) C[i - 1] += C[i];` Think what it does for last iteration i.e. if `i == 0` -> It writes to `C[0 - 1]`. (Actually, if compiled with `_DEBUG` I would expect a violation of an `assert()`...)

Comment: Use `at()` instead of `[]` when accessing the elements of the vector.  If you go out-of-bounds, a `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown.  I bet this is the issue with your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `counting_sort_dec` function, the second `for` loop has the wrong limit. When `i` is zero, the `C[i - 1]` expression refers to an out-of-bounds array element and causes undefined behaviour – which can express itself in many different ways (such as a crash later on in the execution of the program).

Change the loop terminating test from `i >= 0` to `i > 0` in that second loop:

```cpp
vector<int> counting_sort_dec(vector<int>& A, int k) {
    vector<int> B(A.size());
    vector<int> C(k + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        C[A[i]]++;

    for (int i = C.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) // Don't run loop when i is zero
        C[i - 1] += C[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        C[A[i]]--;
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
    }
    return B;
}
```

Note that using the `.at(i)` member function of `std::vector` (instead of direct element access with `[i]`) will help catch this sort of error, as a `std::out_of_bounds` exception will be thrown **at the point of the error** (rather than at some, arbitrary point later on in the execution).

---

In your (working) ascending sort, you start the equivalent second loop at index `i = 1`, so it seems only reasonable that you should end at that point in the descending sort, as the other limits to those two loops are the same (that is, `C.size() - 1`).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a bug here:

```
for (int i = C.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        C[i - 1] += C[i];
```

when `i` equals to `0` your program crashes